# libGDX's 2D particle editor launching incorrectly

Tags: java, libgdx, particles

What's going on? Here's my process:

I first right-click the referenced library for gdx-tools.jar in Eclipse:

[image: ayy lmao]

I then search for the particle-editor class:

[image: ayy lmao]

It opens successfully, but half of the buttons on the right are missing and the preview panel is missing altogether.

[image: ayy lmao]

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed it by updating gdx-tools.jar.

Oops.